# A pattern to disable / restore interrupts

Tags: c++, macros, atomic, interrupt

I'd be very happy and thankful to receive comments on the topic here below.
When it comes to performing some operations with disabled interrupts, I was used to use a couple of macros:

```
START_ATOMIC() do { bool ie = current_interrupt_state(); disable_interrupts()
END_ATOMIC() if (ie) { enable_interrupts(); } } while(0)
```

This assures that the operations in between of START_ATOMIC() and END_ATOMIC() are performed with interrupts disabled and a missing START_ATOMIC() or END_ATOMIC() results in a compilation error.

Given the mantra of many coding standards: *avoid using macros*, I am wondering how safe and expressive the following construct could be.

```
struct Atomic
{
    /* Stores the current interrupt state and disables them. */
  Atomic() : ie_(int_disable()) {}

  /* Restores the original state of the interrupts. */
  ~Atomic()
  {
    if (ie_)
    {
      int_enable();
    }
  }

private:
  bool ie_;
};
```

And have the critical operations performed in a block:

```
{
   Atomic volatile start_critical_section;
   /* Operations performed with disabled interrupts goes here.
}
```

The atomic constructor takes care of saving the interrupt state and disables the interrupts, while the destructor - called when leaving the block - restores the state of the interrupts.

My questions is:
*is there any chance for the compiler not to call the constructor and - mostly - the destructor at the right time/place?*

I expect the constructor being called when entering the code block and - due to the volatile qualifier - the destructor being called just before leaving the code block. The critical operations are performed in between. Am I right, or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance for sharing your opinions.

Comment: I'd suggest adding the [tag:c++] tag, since this is really more about the C++ language than anything.  This is a pretty common RAII pattern and should work fine, e.g. it's the same way that [`std::lock_guard`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) works.  You shouldn't need `volatile` either - I don't think the compiler is allowed to omit a constructor/destructor with side effects, except in situations like copy elision.

Comment: Just make sure that your `int_enable` and `int_disable` functions have the right barriers so that the compiler doesn't think it can optimize them out or reorder them (if you have questions about how to do this, then specify your compiler and explain how `int_enable`/`int_disable` are implemented - inline assembly, etc?)

Comment: I am worried because, while std::lock_guard std::unique_ptr, etc define objects that are usually used in the code following the definition, in this case, the object is defined but unused - I wonder why the compiler isn't complaining about the unused variable - and the code in the functions managing the interrupts is inline assembly.
The compiler might have all the reasons not to strictly follow the sequence I wrote.

Comment: It looks like gcc/clang don't give warnings about unused variables of types that have nontrivial constructors and destructors - probably for exactly this reason.  A `std::lock_guard` object wouldn't normally be used in code other than its definition - the class doesn't even have any public members or member functions aside from its constructor and destructor, so I don't know how you would "use" it even if you wanted to.  So I think it is actually an almost perfect match for what you have here.

Comment: The inline assembly issue only makes a difference if you don't have proper barriers.  For gcc-type inline asm, you need a `volatile` tag on the `asm` statement, as well as a `memory` clobber: `asm volatile("cli" : : : "memory");`  But if you don't have that, then your enable/disable functions are broken regardless of whether you call them from a constructor, or explicitly,  And if you do have it then you can call it any way you want, including from a constructor

Comment: Actually, the suggestion to add barrier instruction is an excellent point. In an ArmV6 environment, this is the implementation of the functions:

`static inline bool int_get_status_and_disable() {` 
`uint32_t primask = 0; `
`asm volatile(" DSB\n"`
` " MRS %0, PRIMASK\n"`  
 ` " CPSID i\n"` 
`" DSB\n" : "=r"(primask));` 
`return primask == 0;` 
`}` 

`static inline void int_enable() {` 
`asm volatile(" DSB\n"` 
`" CPSIE i\n"` 
`" DSB\n");` 
`}`

Comment: You still need the `"memory"` clobber as well.  Otherwise the compiler is free to reorder the `asm` with other loads and stores, in such a way that they might move outside the critical section.

Comment: Actually, I need to go deeper and improve my knowledge about the inline assembly... :-)